# Spark behaving strangely with the cassandra connector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I recently migrated from spark streaming to structured streaming. After some adjustments to the code, it worked normally. However, sometimes it happens that in the middle of the execution the spark throws an exception.

```
21/07/25 11:16:50 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 43.0 (TID 53)
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Keyspace performance does not exist
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:48)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.process(CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.java:59)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.process(CqlPrepareSyncProcessor.java:31)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.prepare(SyncCqlSession.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:43)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.JoinHelper$.getJoinPreparedStatement(JoinHelper.scala:81)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.AbstractCassandraJoin.compute(AbstractCassandraJoin.scala:105)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.AbstractCassandraJoin.compute$(AbstractCassandraJoin.scala:102)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraJoinRDD.compute(CassandraJoinRDD.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The problem is that this keyspace exists, and the job sometimes works correctly for a long time before throwing this exception.

This is code for test:

```
// Read topic kafka
val stream: DataFrame = Kafka.setStructuredStream(ss)
// Parse message to df
val parsed: DataFrame = Stream.parseInputMessages(stream)
// Read cassandra table
val consultant_orders: DataFrame = spark
    .read
    .table("clusterOneTest.performance.codes")
// directJoin parsed message with cassandra data
val joinData = message
      .join(orders,
        Seq("uid","code"))
// Output   
joinData.writeStream
    .format("console")
    .outputMode("append")
    .queryName("Get Codes")
    .start()
```

My conf:

```
val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.sql.extensions", "com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions")
      .set("directJoinSetting","on")
      .set("spark.sql.catalog.clusterOneTest","com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog")
      .set("spark.sql.catalog.clusterOneTest.spark.cassandra.connection.host", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092")
      .set("spark.sql.catalog.clusterOneTest.spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")
      .set("spark.sql.catalog.clusterOneTest.spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")
```

My sbt file:

```
name := "structured-streaming-test"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.14"

idePackagePrefix := Some("com.teste")
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val cassandraVersion = "3.0.1"
  Seq( "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % cassandraVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % cassandraVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % cassandraVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % cassandraVersion,
    "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % cassandraVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % cassandraVersion,

  )
}
```

Can someone help me?

@Edit

```
$ nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
    Name: Test Cluster
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
    DynamicEndPointSnitch: disabled
    Partioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        3c43f6d0-0c71-486f-bca3-0b7539b56591: [192.168.7.145, 192.168.39.87, 192.168.16.81]
```

Comment: What nodetool describecluster shows as schema version? Are all nodes on the same version?

Comment: I added the result of describecluster @AlexOtt

Comment: And yes. All nodes are on the same version @AlexOtt

Comment: For me it looks like a bug. You can open an issue at https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/ - although I’m not sure if it’s Java driver error or Spark error. I would say that it’s Java driver error - in this case - can you try driver version 3.1 for Spark 3.1.x?

Comment: Can the fact that I use two different clusters with catalog generate this kind of bug? @AlexOtt

Comment: Shouldn’t be if you define two different catalog entries. Then it maybe spark connector bug

Comment: I try with version 3.1 for spark 3.1.x and get the same exception. One thing I noticed is that this error only occurs for the cluster that is outside the engine network. One of the catalogs is running on the same server as the engine, and this error is not raised. Only on the outside cluster that the exception is thrown. @AlexOtt

Comment: Then it’s definitely makes sense to file Jira